# Super+number key combos remapping in GNOME 40 (switch workspaces instead of launch docked apps)

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, window-manager, desktop-environment

How to remap <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>*Number*</kbd> key combos in GNOME 40 the easiest way?

I was always searching for a solution on this, when installing Gnome 40. The problem is that by default it opens my favorite "docked" apps, but I want to remap it to switch workspaces instead.

Comment: Sure, go ahead and do so if you find another useful answer on this topic cause I haven't?!! Does somehow stackexchange doesn't allow me to ask the question first and answer my own question after? I don't know of such thing, but even the contrary: They do encourage us to do that.

Comment: I disagree with the close-vote. Self-answering a question is accepted, and the help page even explicitly says _"If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site."_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**After some research I found that as of Gnome 40 you can do it with:**

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter dynamic-workspaces false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences num-workspaces 9
for i in {1..9}; do 
  gsettings set "org.gnome.shell.keybindings" "switch-to-application-${i}" "[]"
  gsettings set "org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings" "switch-to-workspace-${i}" "['<Super>${i}']"
  gsettings set "org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings" "move-to-workspace-${i}" "['<Super><Shift>${i}']"
  gsettings set "org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock" "app-hotkey-${i}" "[]"
done
```

May your htop stats be low and your beard grow long!

Comment: If you use dash-to-dock extension, you may also need to add `gsettings set "org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock" "app-hotkey-$i" "[]"`

Comment: Copy that --> Edited!